# making model null after coming back to same view in mvc after inserting data in database

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a form in view called Role which contains form for filling values for Role.
For this i have use model in view.My code is

```
@using MyProject.Models
@model Role
<h2>AddRole</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm()){ 
@Html.LabelFor(m=>m.RoleName)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.RoleName)<br />

<input type="submit" value="Add Role" />
}
```

After submitting,it goes to AddRole action in my controller,where I am adding this role to database and return back to same view.
code for AddRole is,

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult AddRole(Role role)
 {
 //Code for adding role into database
 using (UserDbContext db = new UserDbContext())
 ViewBag.Message= "Role successfully added.";
 return View("AddRole");
 }
```

After adding values to database,it is still showing the already type values in textboxes.
I want it must not show those values after adding into database.

I think it is,sending that role values back to view,that's why it is showing those values in form.So i try to make that value null in action.But not work.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either do `ModelState.Clear()` or do a `GET` request back to your AddRole page i.e. `return RedirectToAction("AddRole")`. However, the latter would not keep keep your ViewBag.Message;

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
Role newRole=new Role();
ModelState.Clear();  // the fix
return View("AddRole",newRole);
```

Update me if it Worked?

Comment: whats issue, is output same?

Comment: As @david stated try using ModelState.Clear()

Comment: yes it worked by using ModelState.Clear() and also by return RedirectToAction("AddRole") but it is not keeping message in ViewBag,for that I use tempData